# Join two indexes of an array and return the target element, not the object

Tags: javascript

I have defined two variables, one is the last element of an array, the second is the first element of a child array. Individually each variable return the element but when I chain/join(?) them it returns the object.

How can I target the desired element using the variables I have set?

```
//define element
let lineNumber = document.getElementsByClassName('lineNumber');

//get last item in array
let lastLine = lineNumber[lineNumber.length - 1];

//define element
let addButton = document.getElementsByClassName('addLine');

//target specific instance in array (
addButton = addButton[0]; 

//how do I join the two?        
let lastButton = lastLine
+ addButton;

lastButton.style = "visibility: visible;";

console.log(lastLine); //this show the element      
console.log(addButton); //this shows the element
console.log(lastButton );   //this shows the object, should be the first `add button` of the last item on the `lastline` array.
```

Comment: It might help to show your HTML structure. Are `addLine` elements inside of `lineNumber` elements? Do you want to change the `visibility` of the first `addLine` element within the last `lineNumber` element?

Comment: What do you expect to see? You can't add elements together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `lastLine` that you've selected, call `querySelector` on it to get to the first `.addLine` inside it:

```
const addButton = lastLine.querySelector('.addLine');
```

If you want to retrieve *all* `.addLine`s inside, use `querySelectorAll` instead:

```
const addButtonsInsideLastLine = lastLine.querySelectorAll('.addLine');
```

Comment: What if there were multiple .addLine and I want to select a specific one. Can I do:
newVar = querySelector('.addLine');
const addButton = lastLine.newVar[0];

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` to select all `.addLine`s inside, and then you can select the index you want

Comment: so just:
querySelectorAll('.addLine')[0];

Comment: If you *only* want to select the first matching element, you should use `querySelector`. If you want to select one of the matching elements which *isn't* the first index (or if you want to use more than one element of the collection), you can use `querySelectorAll`, eg `addButtonsInsideLastLine[0]` and `addButtonsInsideLastLine[2]`